# Batch> Dir command craps out when denied access to a folder/file, would like it to just SKIP it, or an alternative

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, skip

TLDR: wanna stop DIR from touching folders it can't access, because it crashes out when it tries, or have an other way to do exactly the same audit as DIR /s /b and DIR /s, but with better error handling/ capacity to just skip instead of crashing.

In theory, nothing complicated.

```
DIR /s /b "folder\">"outputfile.txt"
```

Problem, it's on a network. In theory, nothing complicated

```
DIR /s /b "\\servername\sharefolder\">"outputfile.txt"
```

Problem: I'm trying to audit shares from which docker containers are running of.
And DIR just craps out whenever it encounters something it doesn't have access rights to.

I'm trying to basically make an audit, a big file list. I can allow myself to ignore some folders entirely, but I'm not aiming to just make them disappear from the outputfile. I need DIR to not go over them else it flat out nosedives.

Without posting the entire thing, the script is running a bunch of variables to basically make an automated audit of every disk shared with SMB, but even with quite some elevated access to these shares, some folders like ngix or from running apps stay locked... which isn't a bad thing by itself.

The real issue is that every time DIR craps out, the script continuing, effectively just skips the ENTIRE REMAINING of the whole drive share, thus generating stupidly useless audit files.

I'm basically 4hours into it, and I'm going crazy over this more-than-basic command.

The ideal solution would be one I can easilly declare folders to skip if encountered, no matter how deep they are in the folder tree, and possibly also be able to skip folder paths like `appname\foo\ngix`, aka have it skip `ngix` only if in `appname\foo\`.

I would as much as possible be willing to avoid having a .vbs "companion", but I might end up adopting one if it actually does the trick, and spits out the same data format as `DIR /s` and `DIR /s /b` would (because yeah I want both the meta and raw).

Thanks for reading me, and I'm hoping someone will give this failure some help!

Comment: Is it a permissions issue or is it because it's a UNC path? CMD doesn't always play nice with network paths.

Comment: No problem with UNC as far as I can tell. On some drives it just dives 10+ subfolders deep, with spaces and éèàî ect characters in files names without issue.
Really the subfolders that make the DIR command give up are ALL subfolder that aren't accessible through windows file explorer either because of permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can concieve to Achieve this is to double up on the Dir command.
Redirect all output from the first instance to nul and use && as a conditional test to enact the Second instance to Log the Info.

```
REM Check access in the first instance
DIR /s /b "\\servername\sharefolder\">"testaccess.txt" 2>nul >nul && DIR /s /b "\\servername\sharefolder\">"outputfile.txt"
```

Comment: As stated, the issue isn't errors being thrown and showing in the logfile.
It's that it just stops running whenever it encounters a folder it can't access.
And there is more than one folder like that in these shares.
What I would like it to do is:
-have it see that it can't access it and ignore it and go on to the next folder, eventually throwing an error that I'm happy to add to the logs
or
-be able to build an index of folder/subfolder that it would just doesn't try to access.
ex: it it sees the folder ngix/ in a folder called /appname , it doesn't try to access it and just skips it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
DIR /s /b "\\servername\sharefolder\" 2>nul 1>"outputfile.txt"
```

`2>nul` prevents Errors(STDERR) to be redirected to the text file. Only the output is redirected, not errors. So it means dir will not redirect anything to the text  file if any error occurs.

EDIT: Use powershell embedded code to check file permissions use the below script:

```
powershell -command "& {$Folder = "//server/share"; $permission = Get-Childitem $Folder -Recurse | Get-Acl | Foreach {$_.Access} | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -match $UserName} | Select-Object IdentityReference,FileSystemRights; If ($permission) {Exit 0} Else {Exit 1}}"
If %errorlevel% equ 0 ( :: Place dir command here ) Else (Echo no permission & exit /b 1)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to prevent it from stopping, and skipping the rest, when it encounters the issue? _all it does, as far as I'm aware, is not inform you of errors_.

Comment: That's exactly the very issue I'm having.  Finding solutions to hide errors from the output is easy, but that's actually not at all what I'm looking for.  The issue is that whenever it should throw an error for denied permission or something, it doesn't, DIR just silently stops running on after that sub-folder, and the script continues as if the task was completed.
Hence why I ended up needing to ask on here, it's not simply a "want to output errors to nul", it's more like how to stop a command from crashing silently, else by using an other listing method, else with an exclusion index ahead.

Comment: I feel like it will just check for permission in the //server/share/#### location, while some of the troublesome locations are deeper in the folder structure.

Comment: Editing it again. Now it checks recursively every files and folders

Comment: Thanks, but while your first non recursive version worked fine even if it wasn't what I needed, the second throws a parsing error.

The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString